# d3.rebind in D3 v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I found this piece of code online which computes the dijkstra's shortest path algorithm on nodes in a d3 graph. The problem is that d3.rebind has been removed and I haven't found a way to fix this piece of code to make it work. Any suggestions? Also I know this code is not mine so that's why I'm having some problems understanding how to change the code.
Thanks

```
d3.dijkstra = function () {
    var dijkstra = {};
    var nodes;
    var edges;
    var source;
    var dispatch = d3.dispatch("start", "tick", "step", "end");

    dijkstra.run = function (src) {
        source = src;
        var unvisited = [];

        nodes.forEach(function (d) {
            if (d != src) {
                d.distance = Infinity;
                unvisited.push(d);
                d.visited = false;
            }
        });

        var current = src;
        current.distance = 0;

        function tick() {
            current.visited = true;
            current.links.forEach(function(link) {
                var tar = link.target;
                if (!tar.visited) {
                    var dist = current.distance + link.value;
                    tar.distance = Math.min(dist, tar.distance);
                }
            });
            if (unvisited.length == 0 || current.distance == Infinity) {
                dispatch.end()
                return true;
            }
            unvisited.sort(function(a, b) {
                return b.distance - a.distance 
            });

            current = unvisited.pop()

            dispatch.tick();

            return false;
        }

        d3.timer(tick);
    };

   dijkstra.nodes = function (_) {
        if (!arguments.length)
            return nodes;
        else {
            nodes = _;
            return dijkstra;
        }
    };

   dijkstra.edges = function (_) {
        if (!arguments.length)
            return edges;
        else {
            edges = _;
            return dijkstra;
        }
    };

   dijkstra.source = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length)
            return source;
        else {
            source = _;
            return dijkstra;
        }
    };


   dispatch.on("start.code", dijkstra.run);

   return d3.rebind(dijkstra, dispatch, "on", "end", "start", "tick");
};
```

Answer (score 9):

As you know, `d3.rebind()` was removed in D3 v4. [According to Mike Bostock](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/86_jy82NNSY) (D3 creator):

> If you need such functionality you can copy the implementation from v3.

This is the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/v3.5.17/src/core/rebind.js) from v3:

```
// Copies a variable number of methods from source to target.
d3.rebind = function(target, source) {
  var i = 1, n = arguments.length, method;
  while (++i < n) target[method = arguments[i]] = d3_rebind(target, source, source[method]);
  return target;
};

// Method is assumed to be a standard D3 getter-setter:
// If passed with no arguments, gets the value.
// If passed with arguments, sets the value and returns the target.
function d3_rebind(target, source, method) {
  return function() {
    var value = method.apply(source, arguments);
    return value === source ? target : value;
  };
}
```

As you'll see, its use is very straightforward.

So, suppose we have this code, running D3 v3:

```js
var foo = {
  hello: function() {
    console.log("hello");
    return this;
  },
  world: function() {
    console.log("world");
    return this;
  }
};

var bar = {};

d3.rebind(bar, foo, "hello", "world")

bar.hello().world()
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

For having the same code using `rebind` without D3 v3 you just need to copy the original function.

Here is it:

```js
var foo = {
  hello: function() {
    console.log("hello");
    return this;
  },
  world: function() {
    console.log("world");
    return this;
  }
};

var bar = {};

rebind(bar, foo, "hello", "world");

bar.hello().world()

function rebind(target, source) {
  var i = 1,
    n = arguments.length,
    method;
  while (++i < n) target[method = arguments[i]] = d3_rebind(target, source, source[method]);
  return target;
};

function d3_rebind(target, source, method) {
  return function() {
    var value = method.apply(source, arguments);
    return value === source ? target : value;
  };
}
```